# Input "step" is only working on first change of input

Tags: javascript, forms, input, step

I am attempting to change the value of a cart input by increments of 5. I set the value of the 'step' input to 5 with the following code. I would like the input to start at 5 and only go up in increments of 5.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("__BVID__7");
  console.log(input);
  input.setAttribute("min" , "5");
  input.value = 5;
  input.setAttribute("step","5");
}, 2000);
```

The first click up on the input behaves correctly and the value jumps from 5 to 10. However after that the 'step' reverts back to 1 and the values go to 11, 12, 13, etc.

FYI, I have the timeout function set to give the page time to load before I grab the ID. The input I am trying to manipulate is loaded in an iframe.

Comment: The input is being console logged correctly and I can see the correct value, min & step in the DOM

Comment: What's this about an iframe? Depending on its origin, you may not be able to access its contents at all and `document` certainly doesn't refer to the frame's document. Are you sure you're looking at the right `<input>`?

Comment: If the input is in an iframe, do not trust the console. In order to access any values within an iframe you must use `.contentWindow` or `.contentDocument` properties. This only applies if you actually have admin privileges to the page inside the iframe.

Comment: The iFrame is from a custom application that allows me to write code before the page is deployed on the parent. The code above was written on the custom application. I triple checked that the correct input is being selected. I successfully got the value of the input from 1 to 5 and the first 'step' is working, but the code seems to break after that.   Would I use .contentWindow on the parent page? I tried using .contentWindow and i am running into CrossOriginDomain issues.